# How i can display top 3 record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, repeater

I have a repeater in an ASP.NET website that I want to only show the 3 record 
Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul>
         <li><a href='<%# Eval("news_link")%>' > <asp:Label ID="lblNews" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("news_title")%>' /></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

and The entity Model

```
 </asp:Repeater>  
  <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=AGIP_dbEntities" DefaultContainerName="AGIP_dbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="tbl_news" >
  </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Hello, please read [FAQ] and [ask]. Then come back and edit your question.

Comment: Show us your Entity Framework current code.

Comment: You can use .Take, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys but i try this and this work

```
Select="top(2) it.news_title,it.news_link"
```

add it in entitydatasoruce

will be like this

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=AGIP_dbEntities" DefaultContainerName="AGIP_dbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="tbl_news"  Select="top(2) it.news_title,it.news_link">
  </asp:EntityDataSource>
```